# ClickOnce application about to expire

Tags: .net, deployment, certificate, clickonce, publish

I am new to a company where the previous programmer is unavailable for questions.  I have been doing most of my work updating applications on the intranet but now I have been asked to make some changes to a system that is written in VB 2005 and was last published using ClickOnce.  I noticed the certification expiration Date will expire in a few days and I am not sure how to renew it.  I am not familiar at all with ClickOnce, and not exactly sure what will happen when it expires.  I have no information how the certificate was signed or access to a password to resign it if that is what I need.  I see the certificate was issued to and by (our domain name\ Name of previous Programmer).  And looks as though a strong name key file was used:  NameofApplication.pfx. I am working on a new computer(not the same one as the previous programmer) but do have VS 2005 installed. Hoping to find the best way to make a few simple changes to the application and renew the certificate without needing to rewrite the program or reinstall the application on the clients computers. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I found the answer to my own question. I thought I may as well post in case someone may be having the same issue.  I created a new test certificate. To find this open the properties of the application file from Visual Studio select the signing tab.  Click Create New Test Certificate. (Here you can put in your own password)  This test certificate is good for a year.  I had to clean the solution and rebuild the application and then I was able to make changes to the application and republish under the new certificate.  This option will give me time to figure out how to create my own certificates that I can select my own expiration date.